# Media scanner ignores .nomedia on external sd card

Tags: cyanogenmod, external-sd, media-scanner

I have my music on the external SD card on my phone, and use FolderSync to automatically sync podcast files to the same SD card from my computer. There are .nomedia files in the podcast folders (they are synced from the computer), but not in the music folders. When I start SongBird, both music and podcast files show up. Why? What can I do to fix it?

If I wipe the media cache, SongBird shows no music and no podcasts. When I run rescan, it only says "Scanning /storage/sdcard0" (internal SD) but afterwards the media files on the external card (/storage/sdcard1) show up in SongBird.

I use DoggCatcher with virtual feeds (watched folders) to listen to podcasts.

Phone: Samsung GT-i9000 running CyanogenMod 10.1.2-galaxysmtd

Comment: Just to make sure: Have you placed `.nomedia` files (file name beginning with a `.`) in the podcast directories? Maybe also tried placing one in its top-level directory? The title of your question mentions `.media` files: not that you've made the same typo there.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Corrected the title now.  
  
The data structure is (simplified):  
/storage/sdcard1/Media/Music  
/storage/sdcard1/Media/Podcast  
  
so the .nomedia files are two directories down from the SDcard root. I can try moving the directories one level down and see if that helps.

Comment: So you have the `.nomedia` file in `/storage/sdcard1/Media/Podcast`? That should work for all files and directories below it. I don't think the "depth" should be an issue here.

Comment: Different apps interpret .nomedia as different things. If your default file browser isn't reading a certain folder with actual media in it, then I would avoid using .nomedia altogether. (Although I have had quite excellent results with both SDcard AND root files using FX File Browser via the Google Play Market).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a little old, but I will post my findings on it.

This seemed to be a [bug in Android 4.0](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24162). There was an issue in Media Scanner that it ignored the `.nomedia` file in most instances. If you cleared the Media Scanner cache, it would re-index and then honor the .nomedia file.

According to the bug report, it was fixed with this [changeset](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/31110/).